# Tooltip doesn't show

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to use Twitter Bootstrap's tooltips in my newest project. My code is as follows:

```
<img data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" src="..." alt="post title" title="post title">
```

And it doesn't work, although I'd include `bootstrap.min.js` and `bootstrap.css` in my html. I also tried to make it work with JavaScript:

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).tooltip({
        placement: 'left'
    })
});
```

Nothing. What's interesting, normal, "white" tooltip (browser's default) doesn't show also.

Comment: I think you should have this rather than just 'title': data-original-title="Tooltip Text Goes Here"

Comment: Doesn't work either, I tried that before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what files you're loading etc but here's exactly how to use it:

http://jsfiddle.net/pkVjd/

```
<div class="test" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="Tooltip on top"></div>

$('.test').tooltip();
```

Comment: I use the same resources as you. And it works with yours jsfiddle. I copied your code to my images and it doesn't help. i did come to realize, that it's my css fault. But how come? Ive put it here: http://jsfiddle.net/npwbY/